# nx affected:test --base=remotes/origin/master fails on Azure pipeline after Angular and nx upgrade

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have three Angular applications with their libraries in our Nx monorepro. Each app has its own separate pipeline that consist of multiple stages in which application is tested, built and deployed on specific environments. As a branching strategy we're using **mainline** strategy.

Initially we used Node version **14.x** and nx version **12.8.0**. Tests we're run with the command:

```
npx nx affected:test --base=remotes/origin/master
```

After upgrading our Angular and nx versions to the versions 16.14.0 and 15.8.5 respectively.
On our pipelines we install Node and nx with commands:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.14.0'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.npmrc
- script: |
    sudo npm install -g nx@15.8.5
```

And after that we install npm packages and run tests that locally pass but on our Azure pipelines fails:

```
npx nx affected:test --base=remotes/origin/master
```

Error that is returned is:

```
   No tests found, exiting with code 0
node:internal/event_target:916
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                       ^

Error: Unknown worker mes***ge type mes***ge
This is caused by either a bug in Node.js or incorrect u***ge of Node.js internals.
Please open an issue with this stack trace at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at Function.fail (node:internal/assert:20:9)
at Worker.[kOnMes***ge] (node:internal/worker:317:12)
at Mes***gePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:201:57)
at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:446:35)
at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.runTask (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:214:51)
at ZoneTask.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:528:38)
at invokeTask (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:1730:22)
at globalCallback (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:1761:31)
at Mes***gePort.globalZoneAwareCallback (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:1797:20)
at Mes***gePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:647:20)
at Mes***gePort.exports.emitMes***ge (node:internal/per_context/mes***geport:23:28) {
  code: 'ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION'
}
```

nx report produced:

```
 Node : 16.14.0
   OS   : linux x64
   npm  : 8.3.1
   
   nx                      : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/js                : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/jest              : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/linter            : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/workspace         : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/angular           : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/cli               : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/cypress           : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx  : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/storybook         : 15.8.5
   @nrwl/webpack           : 15.8.5
   typescript              : 4.9.5
   ---------------------------------------
   Community plugins:
   @ngneat/transloco        : 3.2.0
   @ngrx/effects            : 15.3.0
   @ngrx/store              : 15.3.0
   angular-auth-oidc-client : 11.6.11
   apollo-angular           : 2.6.0
   rxjs                     : 6.6.3
   @compodoc/compodoc       : 1.1.19
   @ngrx/schematics         : 15.3.0
   @ngrx/store-devtools     : 15.3.0
   @storybook/angular       : 7.0.2
```

If anyone experienced similar issue I would be grateful for any support in solving this problem.